# Python Plone views call others

Tags: python, view, plone

I have a Python function registered as a View in Plone.  I need to be able to call another function from within this registered function.  I'm not sure if it would be best to register this other function as a view as well and try to call that (don't know how to call other views), or if there is a better way to handle this.

Basically I'm creating a function in Python that needs to be callable from other Python functions (that are registered as Views).

- Edit -
  I have tried calling it like any other function:

(pytest.py)
`def Test(self):

    return "TEST"`

And in my Python script registered as a view:

`import pytest

def PageFunction(self):

    return pytest.Test()`

However, this always seems to crash.  If I leave the `pytest.Test()` out and return a simple string, it seems to work fine (so I don't think the `import pytest` line is causing any problems...)

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Normally in Python you should get a traceback when something goes wrong. (Infinite recursion can cause the python interpreter to die without a traceback, especially on Mac OS X. The collective python buildout includes a patch to fix that bug.)

Comment: Good call!  Looking at the traceback led me to the solution!  Thanks Laurence!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import it and call it as any other function.  You don't want to make it a view - that requires you to do a MultiAdapter lookup which is a real pain, and completely unnecessary.

[Edit - strictly using a view is a MultiAdapter lookup, but you can shortcut it via traversal, but that still isn't worth the effort]

Comment: My function definition can't have the typical "self" as a parameter - other than that, this was the solution.

Comment: @blacksheep That's right - "self" is a parameter of a method of a class.  Standalone methods don't have a "self", though you might still need to pass them an object.